# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre declarar una variable con self '''self.variable''' y sin self '''variable''' dentro de un método?

Tags: python

Al sacar los valores de una `<form ...>` encontré que puedo almacenarlos de estas dos formas, `user_post = ...` o usando `self.user_post = ...` , me gustaría saber cuál es la forma correcta de hacerlo, o cuál es la diferencia entre una y otra, de las dos formas el código funciona lo cual es lo mas extraño para mi.

Sin `self`:

```
class SignUpHandler(Handler):

    def get(self):
        self.render('signUp.html')

    def post(self):
        user_post = self.request.get('username')
        passwd_post = self.request.get('password')
```

Con `self`:

```
class SignUpHandler(Handler):

    def get(self):
        self.render('signUp.html')

    def post(self):
        self.user_post = self.request.get('username')
        self.passwd_post = self.request.get('password')
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

La diferencia principal es el **alcance** que tiene cada variable. 
Cuando declaramos una variable como :

```
self.numero = 10
```

Indicamos que el alcance de esa variable es a  **nivel de Clase**, por lo tanto cualquier objeto que instancia esa clase, tendrá acceso a ese atributo. y el valor de la **variable** numero será, por defecto, **10**.

Sí declaramos la variable como

```
 numero=10
```

La variable numero tendrá un alcance dentro del **método** que fue declarada,
por lo tanto no tendremos acceso a la variable desde afuera del método y obtendremos el siguiente error:

```
NameError: name 'numero' is not defined
```

Por lo tanto la forma correcta de hacerlo va a depender de que tipo de programación estas aplicando, por ejemplo, si programás con orientación a objetos, la forma correcta sería definir **clases y atributos**.

Answer (score 4):

Desconozco *app-engine*, pero el funcionamiento de python es muy claro: `self` es una referencia a la instancia, `self.user_post` es un atributo de ella, y `user_post` (sin `self`) es una variable local.

Si guardas el valor como atributo, lo podrás usar en otros métodos que usen la misma instancia. Si lo guardas con variable local, sólo tiene alcance dentro del método en el cual está declarada.

Normalmente, en los códigos de ejemplo te ponen variables locales para darte pistas de cómo puedes trabajarlas, pero no quiere decir que influyan en el funcionamiento del programa. De hecho, si quitas todo lo que hay en el método `post` tendría que funcionar igual (eg: `def post(self): pass`.

Answer (score 2):

La razon por la que necesitas usar `self.` es porque **Python** no usa **@** para hacer referencia a atributos de instancia. En **Python** se decidió hacer los metodos en una forma en que la instancia a la cual pertenece el método sea pasada automáticamente, pero no recibida automáticamente: el primer parámetro del método es la instancia de donde el método es llamado. Esto hace a los métodos completamente lo mismo que funciones y permite que el nombre sea definido por ti (aunque **self** es la convención y la gente generalmente te va reclamar si usas algo diferente.) **self** no es especial del código, es solo otro objeto.

Python podría haber hecho algo mas para distinguir los nombres normales de los atributos (sintaxis especial como **Ruby** lo hace, o requiriendo declaraciones como **C++** y **Java** lo hacen, o quizá algo mas) pero no lo hizo. Python es para hacer todas las cosas explicitas, haciendo obvio que es que y aunque no lo hace completamente en todos lados, si lo hace para atributos de instancia. Por eso al asignar a un atributo de instancia necesita saber a cual instancia asignárselo, y esa es la razón por la que necesita usar **self**.

[Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python).